# USB device authorization: Difference between interface_authorized_default and authorized_default

Tags: linux-kernel, usb

What is the difference between `/sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/authorized_default` and `/sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/interface_authorized_default`? Basically, both of the files are responsible for denying access to newly connected devices to USB ports as [described here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/authorization.txt). They seem to work in the same way, so what's the difference? Which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the new interface authorization [allows to enable or disable individual interfaces per bitmask instead allow or deny a whole device.](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-usb/msg125932.html) It's mentioned in the document you linked to:

*Interface authorization

..........................

There is a similar approach to allow or deny specific USB interfaces.

That allows to block only a subset of an USB device.

..........................

Deny interfaces per default:*

```
echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/interface_authorized_default
```

*Authorize an interface:*

```
echo 1 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/INTERFACE/authorized
```

This is useful when e.g. you need to debug devices & drivers (no matching driver found or wrong driver/configuration used and so on...), [per feature/functionality lockdown of USB devices](https://codedump.net/blog/using-the-linux-kernels-usb-authorization-support-to-lockdown-usb) etc
In a nutshell:

- use `authorized_default` to deny or limit the number of allowed devices
  e.g. deauthorize new devices connected to `hostX` by default

  ```
  echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/authorized_default
  ```

  then connect and authorize the device of your choice:

  ```
  echo 1 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/DEVICE/authorized
  ```
- use `interface_authorized_default` if you need to debug or allow/use only a subset of functionality e.g. deny interfaces on `hostX` by default:

  ```
  echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/interface_authorized_default:
  ```

  authorize the interface of your choice:

  ```
  echo 1 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/INTERFACE/authorized
  ```

  and trigger driver probing:

  ```
  echo INTERFACE > /sys/bus/usb/drivers_probe
  ```

Comment: So, an INTERFACE is just a single USB port or a single USB device?

Comment: @MikhailMorfikov - no... the article linked in my post gives a basic explanation of what happens when a USB device is plugged in. [This answer from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33110026) explains what an interface is... For more details, this is a good place to start: [USB in a NutShell](https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml#DeviceDescriptors)

Comment: I'm in the middle of the vid from that article. :)